# Queue attribute error

Tags: python, queue

I am trying to program a linked list in python using a queue. My problem is that I get an error that I cant understand where it is coming from. I have previously programmed a stack and I did it pretty much using the same "style" of coding.

Why do I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nash\Desktop\Python School\queue.py", line 32, in <module>
    q.put('dim')
  File "C:\Users\Nash\Desktop\Python School\queue.py", line 19, in put
    self.last.next = p

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'
```

I am new to programming so any help is appreciated. Thanks :)
This is my code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = None
        self.next = None

class Queue:

    def __init__(self):
        self.first=None
        self.last=None

    def put(self,x):
        p = Node()
        p.value = x
        if self.first==None:
            self.first = x
            self.last = None
        else:
            self.last.next = p
            self.last = p

    def get(self):
        if self.first==None:
            return None
        x = self.first
        self.first = self.first.next
        return x

q = Queue()
q.put('hi')
q.put('bye')

print(q.get())
print(q.get())
```

UPDATE

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = None
        self.next = None

class Queue:

    def __init__(self):
        self.first=None
        self.last=None

    def put(self,x):
        p = Node()
        p.value = x
        if self.first==None:
            self.first = p
            self.last = p
        else:
            self.last.next = p
            self.last = p
#             self.last.next = None

    def get(self):
        if self.first==None:
            return None
        x = self.first
        self.first = self.first.next
        return x

q = Queue()
q.put('hi')
q.put('bye')

print(q.get())
print(q.get())
```

Ok so now I get this error:

```
<__main__.Node object at 0x028EF770>
<__main__.Node object at 0x028EF7B0>
```

Comment: Note that you should check for `None` with **identity** (`is None`) not **equality** (`== None`). Also, you're checking `self.first` but accessing `self.last`.

Comment: `<__main__.Node object at 0x028EF770>` isn't an error, Python's just printing the object's information because you're printing it as a string instead of trying to access a function in it.

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing `self.last` with `None` in `__init__` and then trying to do `None.next`. That's why you get the error.

You need to put some *not-None* data into `self.last` to get it to work.

Comment: you are supposed to replace this `None` with something prior to accessing attributes of `last`. `None` object has no attribute `next` hence you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't know how to display a Node object. So you have to add a **str**() method defining the way it should display it, like this for example:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = None
        self.next = None
    def __str__(self):
        return self.value
```